# grouping query results by months

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a coldfusion query result, which contains only dates

like

```
2015-07-14 00:00:00.0   
2015-07-22 00:00:00.0   
2015-07-24 00:00:00.0   
2015-07-27 00:00:00.0   
2015-08-04 00:00:00.0   
2015-08-05 00:00:00.0   
2015-08-15 00:00:00.0   
2015-09-01 00:00:00.0   
2015-09-02 00:00:00.0   
2015-09-21 00:00:00.0   
2015-10-14 00:00:00.0   
2015-12-10 00:00:00.0   
2016-01-13 00:00:00.0
```

I want to display query results grouping them on months basis

e.g
Month's name as first column and then dates of that month per row.
I have no idea how to group the query in this sitution.

Comment: Does the database engine you are using have any functions that allow you to cast a date to a string?

Comment: @DanBracuk why would he want to cast a date to a string?

Comment: Matt's answer will get you there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your query to have a `year` and `month` column. You don't specify your DMBS but for MSSQL you would use the `year()`, `month()`, and `day()` functions. Make sure your query is ordered by year, month and day otherwise the grouping will not working properly. ColdFusion also has a built in function called [`monthAsString()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/MonthAsString) to cast an integer to the month name.

```
SELECT year(datecolumn) AS Year, month(datecolumn) AS month, day(datecolumn) AS day, other, columns
FROM mytable
WHERE x = y
ORDER BY year, month, day
```

Output as

```
<cfoutput query="myquery" group="year">
  <cfoupt group="month">
    #monthAsString(month)#
    <cfoutput group="day">
      #day# #other# #columns#
    </cfoutput>
  </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```